# How to create a 3D star view in three.js given the x,y and z coordinates?

Tags: javascript, graphics, three.js

I am trying to create a 3d star view, with a movable camera to traverse stars (js objects) using three.js. In searching for something to get me going/started, I found some code (below) and modified it to what seemed 'logically' correct. The code:

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth /  window.innerHeight, 1, 500);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 100);
camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

// Starlist contains 1600+ stars    
for (var i=0;i<oldstarlist.length;i++) 
{
    // Convert RA/DEC to x,y,z coordinates
    var s0   = new Star(oldstarlist[i]['starname'], oldstarlist[i]['constellation'], oldstarlist[i]['RA'], oldstarlist[i]['DEC'], oldstarlist[i]['lightyears']);

    var star = new THREE.Vector3();

    star.x = s0.coordinates.X;
    star.y = s0.coordinates.Y;
    star.z = s0.coordinates.Z;
    console.log(star.x,star.y,star.z);
    geometry.vertices.push( star );
}

var starsMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial( { color: 0x888888 } );
var starField = new THREE.Points( geometry, starsMaterial );

scene.add( starField );
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

I presumed the 'Points' was correct, and I am still not sure where to place the camera. To be sure, I checked around for any examples and tutorials I could find but found nothing similar to what I am looking for. 
A working example can be found on my test site area at this address:

http://theangelfallseries.com/stars/sp/test3js.html

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean 'camera right place'? your scene is static, nothing would change when rendered,  you can use `requestAnimationFrame()` function to animate your page.

Comment: There are camera coordinates provided; when I change them, the pic changes.

Comment: then you should move on some event like timer or something ... just add some delta to camera position. you can move also in circles to avoid going out of your stars cluster.

Comment: Let me just add this; the camera I believe I can figure out, but the star placement is not working, as you will see if you check my link above.